# window.blur() - what am I doing wrong

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to unfocus a window when it's opened, the situation is:

- I have a main window with a button which open a new window when it's clicked and automatically call the blur() method so the window should be in background, but nothing is happening, I tried it on last versions of Firefox and Chrome.

  ```
  function openWindow() {
    var exampleWin = window.open('example.html','Example','width=500,height=500');
    exampleWin.blur();
  }
  // and the HTML:
  <button onclick="openWindow();">Open Window</button>
  ```

The code is so simple, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work, I even look at the MDN documentation and all seems ok.

**-- Edit --**

Finally I've found a solution with a little different approach:

```
function openWindow() {
            /* This time I don't use var keyword, so the exampleWin variable 
               will have a global scope */
    exampleWin = window.open('example.html','Example','width=500,height=500');
}

function focusFn() {
    exampleWin.focus();
}

function blurFn() {
    exampleWin.blur();
}

// The HTML:
<button onclick="openWindow();">Open Window</button>
<button onclick="focusFn();">Focus</button>
<button onclick="blurFn();">Blur</button>
```

It works properly this way, but just if I call the focus/blur functions with the onclick event, not if I call them inside the openWindow() function, anyway it's fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the main window focus instead:

```
function openWindow() {
  var exampleWin = window.open('example.html','Example','width=500,height=500');
  window.focus();
}
```

Comment: I tried it but the exampleWin is always on foreground, thanks anyway.

Comment: There is actually quite a bit of information on this subject on the net. There are all kinds of issues to consider apparently. Search for 'javascript pop under'. Good luck!

Comment: this DOESN'T WORK AT ALL.

Answer (score 0):

use exampleWin.focus() not exampleWin.blur()

Answer (score 0):

Do this it works better for most conditions...

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"),
        ele = document.createElement('a');

    ele.href = $(this)[0].href;
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    ele.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```